# Cost Effective Constraint check in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to write a procedure to perform daily constraint check on Snowflake Table.

Basically check PK/Unique check and Referential Integrity and Valid Value CHeck.

For PK/Unique: `Performing basic SELECT PK_COL FROM TABLE GROUP BY PK_COL HAVING COUNT(*)>1`

For FK/Referential: `SELECT FK_ID FROM TABLE_1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2 WHERE FK_ID=PK_ID)`

For Valid Values: `SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE GROUP BY 1 MINUS SELECT VALID_VALUE FROM DUAL`

My question is to understand if there are any other better way which are cost effective and use less credit since this process will be run daily.

Comment: These queries look correct, but to optimize we need to get more information: How long are they taking now? What's the shape of the existing data? How is data going to change daily?

Comment: We are dealing with Enterprise Grade DWH having millions of records in table. Right now they are not taking that much time but we dont have continuous run data.

Comment: Hello Ankit, have you considered using streams on top of either table when doing the RI checks? 
You can have as many streams on top of tables as you want, no limit; that way you only check the new rows against another table. I use this approach when checking that my Data Vault satellite tables have matches against its parent hub or link table